# How to obtain signature for AWS call

Tags: amazon-product-api

I am developing a java client and I want to fetch the list of product of my list. But before that I have to authorize a request for which I have to get:

```
?AWSAccessKeyId
&Action
&DateRangeEnd
&DateRangeStart
&DateRangeType
&MWSAuthToken
&MarketplaceId
&SellerId
&Signature
SignatureMethod
&SignatureVersion
&Timestamp
&Version
```

I have all the above mentioned things except signature and signature version.

Anyone has an idea how we can get signature and signature version?

Comment: What are you actually wanting to accomplish with this call? Why are you not using an [AWS SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/tools/) to make the API call?

Comment: i just want to fetch the product list which i have on my amazon web store. i am writing java client to access product list. but first i have to authrize request. i have check aws sdk yet

Comment: Updated tag to amazon-product-api (rather than aws-lambda).

Comment: thanks sir. i can also use this code to make signature.
https://www.javaquery.com/2016/01/aws-version-4-signing-process-complete.html

Comment: @AishaKhan : could you post the solution